# Simple Calculator with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting back into javascript for a job I am going to start soon. for some reason i forgot how to do a simple calculator. I dont understand why my even onclick is null when it is a button. I am sure this is a very simple answer I just cant see it.

```js
if(document.getElementById("add").onclick == true){
   alert("hey");}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TEST</title>
 <script src= "script.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h3> Calculator: </h3>
  <input type="text" name="a">
  <input type="text" name="b">
  <input type="button" value="+" name="add">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you run your own snippet you'll see "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onclick' of null" -- you have no element with `getElementById("add")`

Comment: ^ But that's only the first of your problems.

Comment: Gotta start somewhere :)

Comment: ok i fixed the error. I did not have an ID i put name instead in the html file. However now i have no error and there is no alert box that pops up after i press on the + button

Answer (score 0):

To get you started I made minor changes to your code, go through the changes and understand the use of each change.

```js
function sum(){     
        var a = document.getElementById("a");
        var b = document.getElementById("b");
        alert(Number(a.value) + Number(b.value));
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>TEST</title>
     <script src= "script.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h3> Calculator: </h3>
      <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
      <input type="text" name="b" id="b">
      <input type="button" onClick="sum()" value="+" name="add">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I should of remembered i needed a onclick with a function to load it.... sorry its been a while.

Comment: Then start reading 'JavaScript the weird parts' and then 'You don't know JS' they are very good books to cover JS